# Are validations executed when perform "massive assignment" in Yii?

Tags: validation, yii

I've read an article ["Understanding "Safe" Validation Rules"](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/)

the author said that:

> Key Point - Massive Assignment will only be made for fields which have
>   passed some explicit validation rule. The obvious "actual" validators
>   - length, email, required, etc. - all qualify, but some fields are free form and optional, and don't have any format requirements - the
>   user can put whatever he likes, including leaving it blank.

But there is a [comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/#c5879):

> I admit I haven't taken the time to confirm this thoroughly, but as
>   far as I remember, you are not correct in lumping the validation in
>   with the assignment. If memory serves correctly, when you do massive
>   assignment ($model->setAttributes($_POST['Model'])), no actual
>   validation takes place. Rather, for each attribute in the POST/GET
>   array, the model checks whether that attribute is safe for assignment
>   (by checking whether there is a validation or safe rule for that
>   attribute, without actually validating it) - if there is then it sets
>   the attribute, if not it ignores it.
>
> Validation only takes place when you call $model->save() (or
>   explicitly $model->validate()), when the attributes that have already
>   been assigned are checked using the validation rules.
>
> It is also worth mentioning that massive assignment and individual
>   assignment are not actually equivalent - massive assignment checks
>   whether there is a validation or safe rule for each attribute, whereas
>   if you make an individual assignment ($model->attribute =
>   $_POST['Model']['attribute'];) no such check is made - Yii assumes
>   that the attribution is trusted.

So, any one can show which is the right thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A field can be massively assigned only if it has a validation rule, whose type is not "unsafe". It is not validated upon massive assignment, however.

It is validated when you call validate() or call save(true).

Don't forget that you can read the Yii source code directly in their Class Reference

Comment: yeah, i've read Yii source code and saw that there is not any validation in massive asignment. Thanks for your mention +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Massive assignment happens in two cases - 
1. When you set a validation rule for a field. In that case the field goes through validation.
2. When you declare the field as safe. In this case, you might or might not have a validation rule for a field. The assignment will go through irrespective.

So the correct answer is - 'depends' on if you have a validation rule defined for the field or not.